# Track the changes in design mode in CQ5

Tags: aem

I have done some changes in design mode on a CQ page.
I want to keep track if anyone else is changing the page in design mode.
Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain actions in CQ will leave records in the audit log. Modifying a page is one such action, and changes made in design mode are recorded by modifying the corresponding design page under `/etc/designs`

**To see who has been making changes to a design, just search for "/etc/designs" in the audit log(s) at** `<your-CQ-dir>/crx-quickstart/logs/audit.log`

where you'll find lines like:

```
17.07.2013 22:24:12.722 [46] 5497760921600 admin@crx.default:/etc/designs/default/jcr:content (11143)
```

which show that the user `admin` (logged into the default CRX workspace) changed the design at that date and time.

Designs in CQ can apply to many different pages and the audit log doesn't record what page the user was on when the design was changed, so if that information is important to you you'll need to come up with a way to track that yourself.

For a little more information about auditing changes in CQ, see [Adobe's documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/howto/logsaudits.html#Finding%20the%20Audit%20Records) which also mentions that audit events are recorded under `/var/audit`, which you can explore with CRXDE Lite (though it's more convenient to search the log file).

Answer (score 1):

#### Using basic WCM functionality

You could watch the *last modified* date for a design in CQ5 Tools part of WCM Site Admin

```
http://localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/designs
```

#### Extending your CQ application/installation

Alternatively, you would write an event listener that looked for changes for your design page and produced some kind of notification (e.g email).

#### Analysing the logs

If you have access to the cq request.log you can monitor POST requests to the path of your design.  For example, you might see something like:

```
17/Jul/2013:10:22:00 +0100 [73] -> POST /etc/designs/mydesign/jcr:content/component HTTP/1.1
```

after making a design change.

#### Controlling access to design functionality

Finally, if you only want to control who can modify designs you can control this through a user/groups write permissions on /etc/designs. See ["Removing the design icon from the sidekick in cq5"](http://edivad.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/removing-the-design-icon-from-sidekick-in-cq5/).

Like mszu says the design may apply to many pages so when they change *any* page having that design in design mode then the design, not the page, will be updated.